Sentry.getCurrentScope().setTransactionName(name) not having any effect
I am using Sentry for node.js.  In that context, I have an express route (let's say /myRoute) that has two main branches within it, and the branch chosen to traverse is based on what is passed into the incoming request.  The two branches are quite different and would benefit from being regarded within Sentry as two different transactions.
I have tried calling the following soon after the code branches, to override the transaction name:
Sentry.getCurrentScope().setTransactionName('branchA');
and
Sentry.getCurrentScope().setTransactionName('branchB');
But... I'm not seeing these two transaction names anywhere in my data... in Performance for example I'm just seeing the GET /myRoute/* transaction rather than separate branchA and branchB transactions.
What am I doing wrong?  So far as I can tell I'm just doing what the docs are telling me to do.
